# JFreeChart causing automatic refresh to XHTML page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to build graphs when a page in a Java EE app is loaded. The graphs are building properly, however the page automatically  refreshes over and over again. Has anyone else found this issue? It is as if my code is in an infinite loop but this is not the case.

The below code is in my managed bean java class:

```
public void buildGraph(Integer size) throws IOException {
    for(int i = 0; i < allLoads.length; i++) {
        double [] multipliedLoad = new double[allLoads[i].length];
        // allLoads.length is equal to 6
        // allLoads[i].length is equal to 24
        for(int j = 0; j < allLoads[i].length; j++) {
            multipliedLoad[j] = allLoads[i][j]*size;
        }

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Load Profile Data");
        series = addData(series, multipliedLoad);
        XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Original Load Profile",
            "Hours (hrs)",
            "Power (kVA)",
            data,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            false,
            true,
            false
        );
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        final NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        xAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));

        chart.getPlot().setOutlineVisible(false);
        chart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        chart.getTitle().setVisible(false);

        File file = new File(filename[i]);
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file, chart, 600, 300);
    }
}
```

This code is accessed when the submit button on the previous xhtml page has been pressed.

If I was to remove the save to PNG line then the code does not repeatedly refresh, unfortunately I need this functionality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not `writeChartAsPNG()`?

Comment: @trashgod unfortunately the same thing happens when writeChartAsPNG() is used.

Comment: I can only guess that the problem lies elsewhere in your servlet.

Comment: Thanks for your help @trashgod! I've went through my code step by step and the issue does lie in this method. I have a managed bean class called NavigationBean; two XHTML pages call these 1.xhtml and 2.xhtml; and a class called GraphBuilder where the above method is. The flow of events is as follows 1.xhtml sends an action to NavigationBean to launch 2.xhtml. At the same time NavigationBean calls the above method in GraphBuilder. The graphs are correctly constructed, however this process repeats over and over again and hence refreshes the page repeatedly. I am constructing 6 graphs.

Comment: I've never seen this except with an intentional meta refresh.

Comment: @trashgod no problem, thanks for taking the time to help!